# Eclipse startup Error code=1?

Tags: windows-7, java, eclipse, jdk

I just downloaded [eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR2/eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip) extracted the zip.
When I'm trying to run I get this error:

[image: Error]

Here is my .ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

I'm runing on Windows 7 64-bit (Yes I downloaded the 64-bit JDK and 64-bit Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I would check in Eclipse.ini, if it [points to the right JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Windows_Example). Normally it does not have that line in Eclipse.ini, but it is recommended to put it there.